# Mysql Slow query execution

Tags: mysql, performance

I have one procedure which retrieves all the records from one table which has more than 20000 records and two columns. the column i m trying to retrieve has the index on it.

But still it takes more than 1-2 minutes to execute.

Can anyone provide any input on this.

Comment: You need to provide a lot for information. The layout of the table, the implementation of the procedure, and so on.

Comment: You need to show what query you are using, and a SHOW CREATE TABLE for the table.

Comment: Also, please show the result you get when you execute your query with the "explain" keyword before the "select", eg: "explain select ..."

Comment: The table structure is as follows :
Create table Test 
(
FK_CustID int not null,
FK_OrderID int
);
Both columns has index on it.

Comment: 1, 'PRIMARY', 'Test', 'index', '', 'fk_Test', '8', '', 20434, 'Using where; Using index'
2, 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'Cust', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', 15111, 'Using where'

Comment: That's the `EXPLAIN` output, but what about the original query?  Adding it to the question would help immensely.

Comment: I have sorted this problem as I was using subquery in this. Slow query log helps me out fixing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slow_Query_log was helpful to sort this problem. I was using subqueries in the main query that was the problem.

Thanks for all your support.

Comment: In the future, use SO to get help optimizing your queries, but if you do, make sure that you include your query so people know what you're trying to do. Vague questions, such as, "My query's running slow" give us nothing to go on. We'd really like to help, so give us a chance to!